# Rasterizing stadium shape

Tags: geometry, rasterizing

I want to work with this figure, which is called a stadium:

[image: Stadium shape]

It can be defined, with three parameters, as the set of all the points whose distance with the line segment `[AB]` is less or equal to `r`.

Given an axis-aligned raster of square cells, where each square is defined with two-integer coordinates, what is the most efficient way to compute the set of all cells totally or partially overlapping a stadium? (I don't need here any kind of anti-aliasing)

Problems:

- I can't manage to find a stadium-square overlapping test algorithm
- Even if I had one, I would have to iterate on my whole raster (which is virtually infinite, but on which I could define a finite search zone) and check for each cell whether it is overlapping the stadium. That would be a computationally heavy operation, and I need in my project (a game) a relatively quick operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bresenham circle rasterization algortihms (as well as another ones like midpoint algorithm).

Key point is using symmetry. Let stadium (also has name "capsule") is centered at origin and has parameters: radius `R`, and distance between semicircles `D`

Start from the right point of Bresenham arc (at `(R, 0)` coordinates). Generate points `(x,y)` in order to form circle quarter, and make reflected and shifted points to generate horizontal scanlines

```
(x + D/2 , y) connect to (-x - D/2, y)
(x + D/2, -y) connect to (-x - D/2, -y)
```

For arbitrary orientation is is worth to sort junction points by Y and make upto 5 regions - scanlines arc-arc, arc-line, line-line, line-arc, arc-arc. Then calculate X-end coordinates for every Y coordinate

Comment: Maybe am I misunderstanding your answer, but doesn't that only work when the capsule is axis-aligned? Anyway, I will first try to understand the Bresenham algorithm.

Comment: Yes, such simple approach works for axis-aligned. Will add clues for other cases. You did not mention that stadium can have arbitrary orientation.